# How to focus in div tag in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have created a tabs using div tag in javascript. I have asp.net button on each tab. whenever I clicked on button the focus is set to first tab.

I am using following code in page load event.

```
HtmlGenericControl content_1 = new HtmlGenericControl("content_1");
HtmlGenericControl content_2 = new HtmlGenericControl("content_2");
HtmlGenericControl content_3 = new HtmlGenericControl("content_3");
HtmlGenericControl content_4 = new HtmlGenericControl("content_4");
HtmlGenericControl content_5 = new HtmlGenericControl("content_5");

HtmlGenericControl selectedPage = new HtmlGenericControl(pageName);
content_1.Style["display"] = "none";
content_2.Style["display"] = "none";
content_3.Style["display"] = "none";
content_4.Style["display"] = "none";
content_5.Style["display"] = "none";

selectedPage.Style["display"] = "block";
selectedPage.Attributes.CssStyle.Add("class", "active");
```

Comment: edit and use that editor 1010   which will make the code more readable.

Comment: see.. senior buddys can edit the code.. nice

Answer (score 1):

each div will have unique id.

on clicking div tab, you will get  the id of the div.

Using css style add class active to that div.

Add inactive class to other divs.

When you click another div , remove active class from this and add class to cliked one

Comment: what is this, pseudocode? come on dude, show code. (as simple as it may be). dont be lazy. :)

Comment: let him do something. am sleepy now :)

Comment: @RPM Don't be lazy?  This is SO, where some of the laziest questions get asked.  Zod's answer, though lacking in the English department, should be sufficient.

Comment: trying to make my english better !!. I used to type as we do in chat. Not the full sentence, but the reader can understand.